# PHP/Zend: How to remove all chars from a string and keep only numbers

Tags: php, zend-framework, pattern-matching

I want to keep only numbers and remove all characters from a variable.

For example:

```
input: +012-(34).56.(ASD)+:"{}|78*9
output: 0123456789
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [Zend_Filter_Digits](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html)

> Returns the string $value, removing all but digit characters.

Example with static call through Zend_Filter:

```
echo Zend_Filter::filterStatic('abc-123-def-456', 'Digits'); // 123456
```

Example with Digits instance

```
$digits = new Zend_Filter_Digits;
echo $digits->filter('abc-123-def-456'); // 123456;
```

---

Internally, the filter will use `preg_replace` to process the input string. Depending on if the Regex Engine is compiled with UTF8 and Unicode enabled, one of these patterns will be used:

- `[^0-9]`       - Filter if Unicode is disabled
- `[^[:digit:]]` - Filter for the value with mbstring
- `[\p{^N}]`     - Filter for the value without mbstring

See http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/Digits.php

Comment: Call to undefined method Zend_Filter::filterstatic()......What should I include ?

Comment: @Awan `filterStatic` with a capital S. Also which version of ZF are you using? Note that *prior to the 1.9 release, Zend_Filter allowed the usage of the static get()  method. As with release 1.9 this method has been renamed to filterStatic() to be more descriptive. The old get() method is marked as deprecated.* - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/migration.19.html

Answer (score 11):

This is how to do that generically:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', '+012-(34).56.(ASD)+:"{}|78*9');
echo $numbers;
```

**Output:**

```
0123456789
```

Comment: I'm not a regexp expert so I assume the + in the matching pattern is for "at least one character" but I don't understand why /[^0-9]/ is not enough. Do you have any example ?

Comment: @Benjamin Delichère: To be more specific, the `+` means `match one or more`. If you used only `/[^0-9]/` it won't match up all the instances that might come in throughout the string you are dealing with.

Comment: it is probably tiny little bit faster.